# how to change background color of all panels and containers of sencha touch 2 app

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to change theme of sencha application, i want to know how to change background color of all panels and containers of sencha touch app like [touchstyle application](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/touchstyle/)

I changed the title bar, tab panel color, but i don't know how to change the color of panel and container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the style config.

```
style: {
    background: 'red'
}
```

EDIT:
You could set the `cls` config for your panel. E.g: `cls: red-bg` and in your stylesheet:

```
.red-bg .x-panel-body{
    background-color : red !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, how to change all components into black and there label text into white..

Answer (score 3):

Two ways:

First(Directly change in panel):

```
new Ext.Panel({
    width:200,
    height:200,
    bodyStyle:{"background-color":"red"}, 
    renderTo: document.body
});
```

Second(Add CSS class and use it in Panel's 'bodyCssClass' property):

```
.x-panel-body{
background-color: blue}
```